# Stopwatch in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, stopwatch

I dealing with problem for several days. I have something like stopwatch in recyclerView (a list of users which have stopwatch). Problem is that I do not know how to synchronize it onBindViewHolder and how to add every second 1 second to their time. 
Edited: I added stopwatch class and implemented it. It is working good, but when I scroll, everything is messy. Any ideas how to improve it?

My Adapter

```
class DashboardAdapter(var context: Context?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DashboardAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    lateinit var dataSource: List<User>

    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        var stopwatch: Stopwatch? = null

        val name = view.findViewById(R.id.name) as TextView
        val avatar = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image) as ImageView
        val project = view.findViewById(R.id.project) as TextView
        val playImage = view.findViewById(R.id.play) as ImageView
        val time = view.findViewById(R.id.time) as TextView
        val placement = view.findViewById(R.id.placement) as TextView
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
           holder.stopwatch = Stopwatch(object : Stopwatch.StopWatchListener {
           override fun onTick(time: String) {
                holder.time.text = time
        }
    })
          holder.stopwatch?.start(time.toLong())

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataSource.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.item_dashboard_workers, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    private fun getRealHolderPosition(viewHolder: MyViewHolder) : Int = viewHolder.adapterPosition + 1

    fun setUsers(dataSource: List<User>) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource
    }
}
```

Stopwatch:

```
class Stopwatch(listener: StopWatchListener) {

    interface StopWatchListener {
        fun onTick(time: String)
    }

    private val DELAY : Long = 1000

    private var startTime: Long = 0

    var isRunning = false
        private set

    private var currentTime: Long = 0

    ...

    /**
     * Starts the stopwatch from an offset
     * @param offset The offset in milli seconds
     */
    fun start(offset: Long) {
        stop()
        this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - offset
        this.isRunning = true
        val handler = Handler()
        handler.post(object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                //lock to access running
                synchronized(this@Stopwatch) {
                    if (isRunning) {
                        listener?.onTick(this@Stopwatch.toString())
                        handler.postDelayed(this, DELAY)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun stop() {
        this.isRunning = false
    }

    private fun restart() {
        this.stop()
        this.start()
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun pause() {
       ...
    }

    private fun resume() {
        ...
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Runnable with Postdelay of 1000ms, call increment stopwatch/s at every run + call Notifydatasetchanged();

Comment: I have just tested coutdown and it is working great, unfortunately it's opposite approach :D Could you make some snippet?